# HttpRequestException throwing once hourly

Tags: c#

Updated Content the cachetoken has been called twice in the exact time.
so one went thru to update the refreshtoken the other one error out.

I've set it to async await, why there are two calls calling the same function??
how am i able to prevent that? thanks

---

I have a wrapper that creates a function public async Task getCacheToken created for a few internal/external services/Applications to call, and it's calling every minute or more often.

For some reason I've received only one httpRequestException
hourly with the exact minute and second.

following logs show exception is caught at exact XX:45:01 hourly

I've tried to increase timeout for httpclient and runtime for http,it does not work. I'm really confuse what would actually cause it to throw error just once in exact time.

Thanks so much for reading thru the post.

```
10 Jul 2019 15:20:02.883
 ResultMessage : {"error":"invalid_grant"} Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request). at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at RaisersEdge.Infrastructure.Cache.<GetCacheToken>d__2.MoveNext().Exception: HttpRequestException {"Message":"Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).","Data":[],…Stack: at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at RaisersEdge.Infrastructure.Cache.<GetCacheToken>d__2.MoveNext()Category: Exception
10 Jul 2019 15:20:02.812
 refresh token after update : e96be27ea80140c9a90c2ea06e7a1fd9
10 Jul 2019 15:20:01.528
 refresh token : e2eb37664bb741918d3ebf38587d3801
10 Jul 2019 15:20:01.528
 refresh token : e2eb37664bb741918d3ebf38587d3801
10 Jul 2019 15:20:01.528
 refresh token is null : Yes
10 Jul 2019 15:20:01.528
 refresh token is null : Yes


08 Jul 2019 00:45:01.453
 ResultMessage : {"error":"invalid_grant"} Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request). at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at RaisersEdge.Infrastructure.Cache.<GetCacheToken>d__2.MoveNext(). Message: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).. Stacktrace at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at RaisersEdge.Infrastructure.Cache.<GetCacheToken>d__2.MoveNext()
07 Jul 2019 23:45:01.385
 ResultMessage : {"error":"invalid_grant"} Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request). at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at RaisersEdge.Infrastructure.Cache.<GetCacheToken>d__2.MoveNext(). Message: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).. Stacktrace at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at RaisersEdge.Infrastructure.Cache.<GetCacheToken>d__2.MoveNext()
07 Jul 2019 22:45:01.412
 ResultMessage : {"error":"invalid_grant"} Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request). at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at RaisersEdge.Infrastructure.Cache.<GetCacheToken>d__2.MoveNext(). Message: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).. Stacktrace at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at RaisersEdge.Infrastructure.Cache.<GetCacheToken>d__2.MoveNext()
07 Jul 2019 21:45:01.378
 ResultMessage : {"error":"invalid_grant"} Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request). at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at RaisersEdge.Infrastructure.Cache.<GetCacheToken>d__2.MoveNext(). Message: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).. Stacktrace at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at RaisersEdge.Infrastructure.Cache.<GetCacheToken>d__2.MoveNext()
07 Jul 2019 20:45:01.536
 ResultMessage : {"error":"invalid_grant"} Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request). at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at RaisersEdge.Infrastructure.Cache.<GetCacheToken>d__2.MoveNext(). Message: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).. Stacktrace at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at RaisersEdge.Infrastructure.Cache.<GetCacheToken>d__2.MoveNext()
07 Jul 2019 19:45:01.515
 ResultMessage : {"error":"invalid_grant"} Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request). at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at RaisersEdge.Infrastructure.Cache.<GetCacheToken>d__2.MoveNext(). Message: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).. Stacktrace at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at RaisersEdge.Infrastructure.Cache.<GetCacheToken>d__2.MoveNext()
07 Jul 2019 18:45:01.523
 ResultMessage : {"error":"invalid_grant"} Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request). at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at RaisersEdge.Infrastructure.Cache.<GetCacheToken>d__2.MoveNext(). Message: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).. Stacktrace at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at RaisersEdge.Infrastructure.Cache.<GetCacheToken>d__2.MoveNext()
07 Jul 2019 17:45:01.688
 ResultMessage : {"error":"invalid_grant"} Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request). at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at RaisersEdge.Infrastructure.Cache.<GetCacheToken>d__2.MoveNext(). Message: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).. Stacktrace at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at RaisersEdge.Infrastructure.Cache.<GetCacheToken>d__2.MoveNext()
07 Jul 2019 16:45:01.605
 ResultMessage : {"error":"invalid_grant"} Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request). at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at RaisersEdge.Infrastructure.Cache.<GetCacheToken>d__2.MoveNext(). Message: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).. Stacktrace at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at RaisersEdge.Infrastructure.Cache.<GetCacheToken>d__2.MoveNext()
07 Jul 2019 15:45:01.482
 ResultMessage : {"error":"invalid_grant"} Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request). at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at RaisersEdge.Infrastructure.Cache.<GetCacheToken>d__2.MoveNext(). Message: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).. Stacktrace at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at RaisersEdge.Infrastructure.Cache.<GetCacheToken>d__2.MoveNext()
07 Jul 2019 14:45:01.522
 ResultMessage : {"error":"invalid_grant"} Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request). at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at RaisersEdge.Infrastructure.Cache.<GetCacheToken>d__2.MoveNext(). Message: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).. Stacktrace at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at RaisersEdge.Infrastructure.Cache.<GetCacheToken>d__2.MoveNext()
07 Jul 2019 13:45:01.504
 ResultMessage : {"error":"invalid_grant"} Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request). at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at RaisersEdge.Infrastructure.Cache.<GetCacheToken>d__2.MoveNext(). Message: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).. Stacktrace at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at RaisersEdge.Infrastructure.Cache.<GetCacheToken>d__2.MoveNext()
07 Jul 2019 12:45:01.533
 ResultMessage : {"error":"invalid_grant"} Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request). at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at RaisersEdge.Infrastructure.Cache.<GetCacheToken>d__2.MoveNext(). Message: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).. Stacktrace at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at RaisersEdge.Infrastructure.Cache.<GetCacheToken>d__2.MoveNext()
07 Jul 2019 11:45:01.418
 ResultMessage : {"error":"invalid_grant"} Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request). at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at RaisersEdge.Infrastructure.Cache.<GetCacheToken>d__2.MoveNext(). Message: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).. Stacktrace at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at RaisersEdge.Infrastructure.Cache.<GetCacheToken>d__2.MoveNext()
07 Jul 2019 10:45:01.420
 ResultMessage : {"error":"invalid_grant"} Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request). at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at RaisersEdge.Infrastructure.Cache.<GetCacheToken>d__2.MoveNext(). Message: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).. Stacktrace at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at RaisersEdge.Infrastructure.Cache.<GetCacheToken>d__2.MoveNext()
07 Jul 2019 09:45:01.443
 ResultMessage : {"error":"invalid_grant"} Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request). at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at RaisersEdge.Infrastructure.Cache.<GetCacheToken>d__2.MoveNext(). Message: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).. Stacktrace at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at RaisersEdge.Infrastructure.Cache.<GetCacheToken>d__2.MoveNext()
07 Jul 2019 08:45:01.393
```

This is my code

```
    public async Task<string> GetCacheToken()
    {
        ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
        string refreshToken = cache.Get("refreshToken", null) == null ? GetToken() : cache.Get("refreshToken", null).ToString();

        if (!cache.Contains("apiToken"))
        {
            //Log.Information("Access token " + cache.Get("apiToken", null));
            var isNull = cache.Get("refreshToken", null) == null ? "Yes" : "No";
            Log.Information("refresh token is null : " + isNull);
            Log.Information("refresh token : " + refreshToken);

            var httpContent = new StringContent("", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dict.Add("grant_type", "refresh_token");
            dict.Add("refresh_token", refreshToken);
            var requestData = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                RequestUri = new Uri("https://oauth2.sky.blackbaud.com/token"),
                Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict)
            };

            requestData.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Settings.BasicAuth);
            var results = await _client.SendAsync(requestData);
            var resultResponse = results.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            try
            {
                results.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                var result = _js.Deserialize<TokenModel>(resultResponse);
                //token expires in one hour from blackbaud
                var expiration = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(55);
                cache.Set("apiToken", result.access_token, expiration);
                cache.Set("refreshToken", result.refresh_token, expiration);
                UpdateToken(result.access_token, result.refresh_token);
                Log.Information("refresh token after update : " + cache.Get("refreshToken", null));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var exceptionMessage = $"ResultMessage : {resultResponse} Exception: {e}.";
                Log.Exception(e,exceptionMessage);
                throw;
            }
            //Log.Information("after update access token " + cache.Get("apiToken", null)); 
        }

        return cache.Get("apiToken", null).ToString();
    }
```

This is the end point for external apps to call

```
    public async Task<string> getAccessToken()
    {
        return await cacheToken.GetCacheToken();
    }
```

For external App this is how they get the AccessToken

```
    protected string getAccessToken()
    {
        var requestData = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Get,
            RequestUri = new Uri($"Settings.Api/getAccessToken"),
        };

        requestData.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _token);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/plain"));
        var results = client.SendAsync(requestData).Result;
        var resultResponse = results.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        if (results.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            return resultResponse.Replace("\"", "");
        return "";
    }
```

Then pass it in here, this is just one of the sample, there are more then 10? places to call getCacheToken

```
protected override ExtractResultStatus PerformExtract()
    {
        try
        {
            var dt = GetInfos();
            var fileName = String.Format(FilenameBase, DateTime.Now);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                dt.Columns.Add("FailureReason");
                var numErrors = 0;

                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    var success = true;
                    var numberOfTries = 0;

                    // Post Cons custom fields

                        numberOfTries = 0;
                        do
                        {
                            var token = getAccessToken();

                            if (token != null)
                            {
                                var content = CreateCCFModel(row);
                                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);
                                var httpContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                                var requestData = new HttpRequestMessage
                                {
                                    Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                                    RequestUri = new Uri($"Settings.api/customfields"),
                                    Content = httpContent
                                };

                                requestData.Headers.Add("Bb-Api-Subscription-Key", _bb_Api_Subscription_Key);
                                requestData.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                                var results = client.SendAsync(requestData).Result;
                                var resultResponse = results.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                                if (!results.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                                {
                                    row["FailureReason"] += " Failure reason: " + resultResponse;
                                    numErrors++;
                                }

                                if (results.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
                                {
                                    success = false;
                                    numberOfTries++;
                                    if (numberOfTries >= 3)
                                    {
                                        throw new Exception("500 response returned three times");
                                    }
                                }
                                else success = true;
                            }
                        } while (!success && numberOfTries <= 3);

                }
                SendDataToClients(targetContactEmails, dt.Rows.Count, numErrors, fileName);
            }

            File.WriteAllBytes(_dataFilePath + fileName, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dt.ToCsv()));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Exception(e, LogCategory, LogSeverity.Warning);
            SendErrorEmail(e);

            return ExtractResultStatus.Failure;
        }

        return ExtractResultStatus.Success;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code that's calling it? You said "internal/external services/Applications" this could be a case of an external application calling your API incorrectly and your API doing what it's supposed to

Comment: Sorry just turned off my computer, there are about 10 processors calling it constantly and it shouldn't be causing it throwing at exact time.
Sorry I'll post include the calls when I have my codes with me. Thanks

Comment: I've updated my post, get CacheToken has been called twice at the same time even its from a await call